# vscode ignore [ts] Cannot find module

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, how to ignore TypeScript errors for some files?

I have some auto-generated `*.ts` files, and when they're opened, they show red in Explorer with errors like

```
[ts] Cannot find module 'some-module'
```

I want to ignore those files from the linting/checking for errors.

Comment: I'm not aware of a simple way to do this.  Why do you have files that reference nonexistent modules?

Comment: They are files for GraphQL Bindings, that are then used on multiple other apps. On those apps, the modules (should) exist. On the app they are created, it would be nice to open them without getting them littered with errors from the IDE.